# WALA:“Could not create a entrypoint callsites:” problems

Tags: java, slicers

I am using WALA to conducting static analysis, but I met some problem. When I buliding call graph, some jars have these problem :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not
>   create a entrypoint callsites:
>
> 1. [Moderate] class
>      com.ibm.wala.ipa.cha.ClassHierarchy$ClassExclusion :
>       No superclass found for
>       Superclass name
>      Lorg/eclipse/swt/dnd/ByteArrayTransfer
> 2. [Moderate] class 
>      com.ibm.wala.ipa.cha.ClassHierarchy$ClassExclusion :
>       No superclass found for
>       Superclass name
>      Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Canvas
> 3. [SEVERE] class 
>      com.ibm.wala.classLoader.BytecodeClass$ClassNotFoundWarning :
>      Lorg/eclipse/swt/dnd/DragSourceListener
> 4. [SEVERE] class 
>      com.ibm.wala.classLoader.BytecodeClass$ClassNotFoundWarning :
>      Lorg/eclipse/swt/dnd/DropTargetListener
>
> com.ibm.wala.ipa.callgraph.propagation.PropagationCallGraphBuilder.makeCallGraph(PropagationCallGraphBuilder.java:263)

the wala seems cannot get the eclipse.swt package‘s .class file, and so I cannot build a Call Graph to slice.
Did you meet any problems like this? This problem brother me for a long time.
the problem Jar like this ：http://mirror.bit.edu.cn/apache/commons/io/binaries/

the WALA version is 1.4.3.
and my code is :

```
AnalysisScope scope = AnalysisScopeReader.makeJavaBinaryAnalysisScope(jarPath, exFile);
ClassHierarchy cha = ClassHierarchyFactory.make(scope);

Iterable entrypoints = Util.makeMainEntrypoints(scope, cha);
AnalysisOptions options = new AnalysisOptions(scope, entrypoints);// the problem line
options.setReflectionOptions(ReflectionOptions.NONE);
```

So ,how do I deal this problem.Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

I want to know what code does your jarPath contains. Because I found your entrypoints made by `makeMainEntrypoints` method, this method requires that the source code of the binary you are analyzing must contain the main method.

If it does not contains the main method, you can use`AllApplicationEntrypoints` class to build entry points like this:

```
Iterable<Entrypoint> entrypoints = new AllApplicationEntrypoints(scope, cha);
```